# how to remove carrierwave auto generated json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, active-model-serializers

I am using jquery-file-upload to upload avatar image file to carrierwave with rails.

The controller:

```
class Api::V1::AvatarsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :user
  load_and_authorize_resource :avatar, through: :user
  respond_to :json

  def create
    @avatar.active = true
    @avatar.save
    respond_with @avatar, location: nil
  end
end
```

I also use active_model_serializers to generate json:

```
class AvatarSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  attributes :active
  attributes :image
  attributes :crop_x
  attributes :crop_y
  attributes :crop_w
  attributes :crop_h

  attributes :image_medium_path
  attributes :image_large_path
  attributes :can_manage

  attributes :user_id

  def image_medium_path
    object.image_url :medium
  end

  def image_large_path
    object.image_url :large
  end

  def can_manage
    Ability.new(scope).can?(:manage, object)
  end
end
```

After I upload avatar image using jquery-file-upload, I got response:

```
  {"avatar":{
      "id":"51eba3143803f8aa7c000009",
      "active":true,
      *"image":{
        "image":{
          "url":"...",
          "large":{
            "url":"..."
          },
          "medium":{
            "url":"..."
          },
          "small":{
            "url":"..."
          },
          "xsmall":{
            "url":"..."
          },
          "xxsmall":{
            "url":"..."
          }
        }
      },*       "crop_x":0,"crop_y":0,"crop_w":294,"crop_h":294,"image_medium_path":"...","image_large_path":"...","can_manage":true,"user_id":"51e4156a3803f8cde900000b"}}
```

As you can see the "image" section of json is carriverwave added part. I want to delete it. how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just solved similar problem by overriding to_json method.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def to_json(options = nil)
    params = {field: self.field,... image: self.image.url}
    ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(params, options)
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm with the same problem using active_model_serializers gem. Do you know what can I do?